# Why is my array returning a repeated single value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numerical-methods

I have this code which is supposed to return a list of different spatial distances. However, when I print the array, it is only a single value filled in the array which is clearly wrong. The logic behind is

First step: find as much location(x,y) possibilities as possible then

create an ellipse image relative to an angle which is to be kept fixed (theta) and a location(x,y)

Second: Compute the spatial distance between the pixels of the ellipse and the abstract binary image [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFEEl.png) both images with the same dimensions because they are to treated as arrays

Third : store the spatial distances in an array/list

```py
combinations = []

def points (x,y):
    dx = 5
    dy = 5
    return x + dx, y + dy

for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
        combinations.append(points(x,y))

print(combinations)
```

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial import distance
import scipy.misc
im = scipy.misc.imread(r'C:\Users\mbore\Pictures\irregular1.png', flatten=False, mode='L')


#to store the spatial_distances calculated
distances = []


#getting the dimensions of the image -> y
yDim = im.shape[0]

#getting the dimensions of the image -> x
xDim = im.shape[1]


#initialize empty array this array will receive all the white pixels 
a = np.empty([100,100])

for i in range(yDim):
    for j in range (xDim): 
        if np.any(im[i,j]) == 0:
            a = np.append(a,im[i,j],axis=None)

def ellipse(x, y):
    value = (x*x) + (y*y)/3
    if (value >= 600):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def translate(x, y, DX, DY):
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

def rotate(x, y):
    theta = np.radians(45)
    matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return matrix@(x,y)

data = np.zeros((100,100))

for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        for DX,DY in combinations:
            (x, y) = translate(i,j, DX, DY)
            (x, y) = rotate(x, y)
            data[i] = ellipse(x, y)
            a = a.flatten()
            data = data.flatten()
            a = a[0:10000]
            spatial_distance = distance.hamming(data,a)
            distances.append(spatial_distance)
```

Comment: Maybe as a start, get rid of those nested loops and use numpy vectorization. This will make your code a lot shorter and easier ot follow (and faster). e.g. if `im` is 3D (maybe it has colour?) `counter = sum(~np.any(im, 2))` or if it is 2D then `counter = sum(im == 0)`. You can do something similar for all your loops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also take a look at `np.meshgrid` to create `combinations` in one go. Use a single matrix multiplication to apply your rotation matrix (i.e. `@` instead of `np.dot` in a loop).

Comment: @FlorianH I have made a few changes

Comment: @Dan I do not understand your second comment with regards to the rotation matrix

Comment: For example, if you have a matrix of coordinates like `x = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]])`, you can find the rotated coordinates in one shot like this `rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])` and then `x_new = rotation_matrix @ x`. This is instead of what you are doing which is to loop through this and then take the dot product of each row of `x` with your `rotation_matrix`. Just check my dimensions, I might have something transposed incorrectly.

Comment: which array are you getting a single entry for? your code works fine for me

Comment: @DrBwts when you print distances, it has repeated one value

Comment: ahh OK that is a different issue I'll delete my answer

Comment: @Dan thank you, I have implemented your suggestion however the result of the code is still the same

Comment: @M.Bore No, I don't mean you should do that inside your rotate function, my point is to use it so you can get rid of your loops. Your loops are making your code very bloated and hard to follow, read up about vectorization in numpy. Get rid of your loops completely. Then maybe we can spot your error.

Comment: I'm getting some very odd values in `a` either very small, very large, 0 or `nan` is that what you are expecting?

Comment: why are you using `a = np.empty()`? Because that is filling `a` with all sorts of garbage!